# Static analysis: 2 errors were found during analysis. SQL Error

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

An opening bracket followed by a set of values was expected. (near "ALTER" at position 571)
Unexpected token. (near "ALTER" at position 571)

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''eyecolor', 'flag') VALUES

(1, 'Иван', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', ' at line 5

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time:  7 апр 2020 в 09:51
-- Версия на сървъра: 10.4.11-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.4.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `personbase`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура на таблица `persons`
--

CREATE TABLE `persons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) COLLATE utf32_bin NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(25) COLLATE utf32_bin NOT NULL,
  `height` varchar(30) COLLATE utf32_bin NOT NULL,
  `haircolor` varchar(30) COLLATE utf32_bin NOT NULL,
  `eyecolor` varchar(30) COLLATE utf32_bin NOT NULL,
  `flag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_bin;

--
-- Схема на данните от таблица `persons`
--

INSERT INTO `persons` (`id`, `name`, `family`, `height`, `haircolor`, 'eyecolor', 'flag') VALUES
(1, 'Иван', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 0),
(2, 'Стефан', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 1),
(3, 'Калин', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 0),
(4, 'Димитър', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 1),
(5, 'Алекс', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 0),
(6, 'Иван', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 1),
(7, 'Мартин', 'Петров', '173', 'Кафяв', 'Син', 0),

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `persons`
--
ALTER TABLE `persons`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `persons`
--
ALTER TABLE `persons`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You are using different type of quotes for eyecolor and flag columns. Unify them.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! But I have one more problem. After fix it and trying toimport it have that

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `persons`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)' at line 21"

Comment: You are using wrong syntax, read MariaDB documentation https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/primary_keys.php and search for 'Create Primary Key - Using ALTER TABLE statement'